# How to unlock my iPhone without knowing my password?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I locked myself out of my iPhone, I don't know my password... it isn't disabled, but when I try to connect to iTunes I get this message: "To allow access, please respond on iPhone". I can't respond on my iPhone because I cannot get into it! Someone help me please. I've been trying to do this for over 3 hours and nothing is working!

Comment: Start at https://iforgot.apple.com. No one else can help.

Comment: @Tetsujin, isn't iforgot.apple.com for resting one's Apple ID password or can one also reset an iDevice passcode from there as well?

Comment: @user3439894 - the OP said password - I never even thought of pass*code* tbh

Comment: @user3439894 - my excuse is it was 5.30 am & I was on my phone, hugging my first coffee of the day ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> I locked myself out of my iphone

That was silly of you

> I don't know my password...

Even sillier. You are required to know your password. It's 2015 - passwords are as essential to modern life as keys.

Take your phone, contract, purchase receipt etc. to the nearest Apple store. They can reset your account access.

Note that if your next comment is "I lost my paperwork" then you will probably end up buying a new phone.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to erase the iPhone.

If you have a backup of your iPhone, you can load a backup after you erase the iPhone.

If you don't, and you erase it, you are out of luck.
[Here](http://m.imore.com/how-to-put-iphone-ipad-recovery-mode) is a guide on how to erase the iPhone.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the computer that this iPhone is synced to, then you have a chance to recover the data.
When you plug the iPhone in, despite it being locked, it should still perform a sync and backup.

Double check that it did do that, by noting the time when it was last backed up in the Summary section.

Check again that it did, in fact, backup recently. This is the last chance before erasing your iPhone.

Now you can perform the restore, gain access to the iPhone and restore from the backup you just made.

If you were really cautious, you could use a different phone that can be erased, to restore this just made backup to test it will work.

Comment: To address the OP again, it sounds like they are trying to use a computer that this iPhone had not been synced with. Try and find the computer that the iPhone was synced with previously and try again. If you don't have that computer anymore, or it was reinstalled or such, then you are indeed out of luck. You can certainly erase the iPhone and start again, but I'm afraid your data is gone, unless your had a local backup or iCloud backup.